# Sending Toast and Tile notification together in Windows Phone

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-7.1, mpns

Is it possible to send Toast and Tile notifications together in Windows Phone? I want to receive Toast as well as Tile notification at the same time on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560068/sending-a-tile-and-toast-notification-through-at-the-same-time) suggests it's possible, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202945%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says otherwise:

> Form the message for the appropriate notification type. The following sections describe the message formats for toast, Tile, and raw notification messages. You can post only one notification type (toast, Tile, or raw) to the server at a time. If you want to send multiple notification types to the same client device at the same time, you must create separate POST messages for each notification type.